# How do I change the timeout on Beagle Bone Black's watch dog timer?

Tags: beaglebone

In beagle bone black (and variants) there is a watchdog timer that is activated by writing to the relevant file. It's time out is 60 seconds. I need it's time out to be 10 seconds. Reason : I am controlling a heating element. Waiting 60 seconds to switch the element off (by warm rest) could result in a fire. I estimate that 10 seconds of loss of control would be the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally change this via programming the watchdog interface, *if* the interface supports it, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411582/692658

Another way it's possible (but depends on if the driver supports it) is via the watchdog.conf file which would be in /etc/watchdog.conf.

Simply putting `interval = 10` should set the interval to be 10 seconds. Source: https://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf

However, if you don't understand what you're doing with this, you should likely reconsider your approach, especially if the failure state could cause harm or death. There is other safety ideals you could incorporate such as thermal cutouts, or a simpler system to provide the power instead of the BBB.

Comment: Define simpler? Any solution that uses a micro controller would have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `wdctl -s your_timeout` to set the timeout for default watchdog.
You can see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wdctl.8.html).